# Decrypt the cookies stored by the MS Teams desktop client

Tags: encryption

I am creating a digital forensic tool that gets all data of user from different platforms. I successfully have done extraction for Teams website but I am unable to do so for the desktop app. So far, I know that the cookies are stored in Local/Microsoft/Teams folder. The file has no extension although it is an SQLite3 database. It shows all the cookies but these are in encrypted form. Is there any way I can get the actual decrypted cookies?

> 1. If the server encrypts cookies, it does not mean that the client is able to decrypt them. The client must just send back all the cookies to
>    the server.

The server is not encrypting instead the client desktop app is. The Microsoft API use plain cookies. And I can not use the encrypted ones in browser as that will not start session.

> 1. Why do you think they are encrypted in the first place instead of just being some identifier into a backend database with the actual
>    data?
> 2. What makes you think that the client (and thus your tool) would have access to the key to decrypt the data - wouldn't this defeat the
>    purpose of encryption in the first place?

I think they are encrypted because they are under the column "encrypted value".

[image]

I have found a library that decrypts cookies stored by chrome and other browsers. I think we can decrypt the MS Teams cookies if we have the keys for it using the following code

```
import browser_cookie3

c = browser_cookie3.chrome(cookie_file=r"C:\Users\Farhan Ahmed\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Microsoft\MSTeams\EBWebView\Default\Network\Cookies",
                            key_file="Key file")

for cookie in c:
    print(cookie.name, end=" ")
    print(cookie.value)
```

The code does not work for now and give some errors. I am checking why that is happening.

I will appreciate if someone shares a better way of doing it.

Comment: 1. Why do you think they are encrypted in the first place instead of just being some identifier into a backend database with the actual data? 2. What makes you think that the client (and thus your tool) would have access to the key to decrypt the data - wouldn't this defeat the purpose of encryption in the first place?

Comment: Electron has the safeStorage function for such things. I'd look into what Edge webview2 provides.

Comment: If the server encrypts cookies, it does not mean that the client is able to decrypt them.The client must just send back all the cookies to the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I think I have access to browser cookies so why not the App session cookies stored in disk. The root should have access to his cookies when he wants.  I think they are encrypted because they under the column encrypted value. I am new to cyber security and recently started my degree, so I do not have enough knowledge

Comment: @mentallurg The server is not encrypting instead the client desktop app is. The microsoft api use plain cookies. And I can not use the encrypted ones in browser as that will not start session. Still I will try once to confirm

Comment: 1) Please add this statement to the question. 2) See the question of Steffen Ulrich above: Why do you think they are encrypted? Again, please add the answer to you question.

Comment: @vidarlo  I have done a edit. It might help you

Comment: @mentallurg  I have done a edit. It might help you

Comment: @SteffenUllrich  I have done a edit. It might help you

Answer (score 3):

Just so you know, I think this has already been done - https://github.com/sleuthkit/autopsy_addon_modules/tree/master/IngestModules/Microsoft_Teams_Parser

You could just browse the code at https://github.com/lxndrblz/forensicsim/ to get an understanding of how the Teams data is stored.

Comment: I have checked it, It gets data for forensic but according to it the cookies are not encrypted but they are. This also helps a lot but if I can get cookies that will be great

Comment: Awarded you the bounty, because I got my work done with this tool. Although I would still prefer cookies. Thanks for your help